# I'm looking for a word to mean less enthusiastic in a positive demeanor

Tags: synonyms

I'm trying to convey to someone that he is too "enthusiastic" and I would like him to calm down a little bit but done with a positive tone.

Comment: If you allow yourself more than on word, you could suggest that the person "restrain [or _moderate_] [his or her] zeal."

Comment: Yeah, more than one word is allowed and I love it! Thanks

Comment: So you want your friend to be a bit more subdued?

Comment: Coworker, but yes :)

Comment: [Cool](https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/6503171/Leonard+Bernstein/%22Cool%22+%5BFrom+West+Side+Story%5D) from "West Side Story" has many ways to say it.